# Turn off date parsing on morris chart

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, charts, morris.js

I am using morris chart on my web project. I need to change years on "X label" to days (dd.mm). My code is here:

```
    <div id="morris-area-chart"></div>
<script>
    Morris.Line({
      element: 'morris-area-chart',
      data: [
        { b: '20.12', a: 0 },
        { b: '21.12', a: 2 },
        { b: '22.12', a: 50 },
        { b: '23.12', a: 75 },
        { b: '24.12', a: 50 },
        { b: '25.12', a: 75 },
        { b: '26.12', a: 10 }
      ],
      xkey: ['b'],
      ykeys: ['a'],
      labels: ['AZN'],
      hideHover: 'auto',
      resize: true
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. I need to add this parameter to my JS code:

```
parseTime: false
```

After adding this parameter to JS code, Morris chart won't parse dates.